# Still having problems with flicker/blinking on page transitions with jQuery Mobile on Android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I see this has been talked about for many years but it is still happening.

I have an app that uses jQuery Mobile in iOS and everything is fine.  I'm now trying to deploy to Android but there's a horrible flickering on page transitions.  I've tried many solutions proposed on the web but none work.  The only thing I've found to work is to turn off jQuery Mobile, which I don't want to do!

I've tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

and

```
.ui-page {
    text-shadow: none!important;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and

```
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning,
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-page {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
        {
           if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1)
           {
             $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
             $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
           }
        });
</script>
```

and adding this to the Android manifest

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

and probably others I'm not remembering.

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.  Cordova 6.3.1.  Testing on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1 and on an LG G3 running 5.0.

There's an open issue on the jQuery Mobile github page but no one has answered in over a year.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

- Jon

Comment: I know that the jQuery Mobile versions are different but did you try the following trick: http://outof.me/fixing-flickers-jumps-of-jquery-mobile-transitions-in-phonegap-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I had a few window.location page transitions in my code.  When I changed them to use $.mobile.changePage(page) and made sure I had

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
```

No more flicker!

- Jon